# C# fluent validation of interface underlaying object

Tags: c#, azure-functions, fluent

I got an azure function, I receive a Json the json contains

```
List<Iinterface> objects {get;set;}
```

then I can have several object implementing Iinterface

```
public class A : Iinterface { ... }
```

The json converter actually resolves the types, so on a list's item if I invoke .GetType i get the correct underlaying type!

But then I need to validate according to the underlaying type!

I got this, but can I do it better?

```
public class IinterfaceValidator : AbstractValidator<Iinterface>
    {
        public IinterfaceValidator (AValidator aValidator)
        {
            When(x => x.GetType() == typeof(A), () =>
            {
                RuleFor(x => (A)x)
                    .SetValidator(aValidator);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: It looks good, what is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

A little cleaner implementation would be to use `SetInheritanceValidator`. Suppose you have validators `AValidator` and `BValidator` for below classes respectively.

```cs
public class A : Iinterface { ... }

public class B : Iinterface { ... }
```

Then you define a validator for `Iinterface` like below. Note I am using lazy initialization of child validators to avoid creation of instance during initialization.

```cs
public class IinterfaceValidator : AbstractValidator<Iinterface> 
{
    public IinterfaceValidator() {
        RuleFor(x => x).SetInheritanceValidator(v => {
            v.Add<A>(i => new AValidator())
             .Add<B>(i => new BValidator());
        });
    }
}
```

You can also have a look at their inheritance example [here](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/inheritance.html).